# RMI registry not available error

Tags: java, exception, unix, garbage-collection, rmi

I am runing JBoss AS 5 on Unix. I want to start visualGC remotely from windows 7.

First, I have create an RMI Registry on port 8725 -because the RMI registery default port was busy- using the command `rmiregistry 8725 &`.

Second, I tried to start a jstatd server using the command `jstatd -p 8725 -J-Djava.security.policy=/app/home/user/jstatd.policy`

Third, I started the Jboss Server.

Fourth, I got the process id of the server which is `8627`.

Last, I returned to windows 7 and I tried to run this command `visualgc 8627@XX.XXX.X.XX:8725`.Unfortunately it returned with the following error:

`RMI Registry not available at XX.XXX.X.XX:8725
Connection refused to host: XX.XXX.X.XX; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because the RMI registry default port was busy

*Why* was it busy? Port 1099 has been reserved by the IETF for the RMI Registry since at least 1996. Maybe there was already an RMI Registry running?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

That means that that host:port is reachable from your host but did not respond. Maybe there is a firewall in the way?

Comment: Thanks. However, I got a new error msg `Remote Exception attaching to rmi://9489@10.195.5.73:31111`